# Наложение изображений в таблице

Tags: swift, изображения

Существует таблица, в которой помимо текста есть картинки в каждой ячейке. В таблице около 3 000 позиций, картинки грузятся по url, которые получаю через парсинг. 
При плохом интернете или же быстром скроллинге таблицы происходит наложение картинок, я думаю вам известна эта проблема, когда в одной ячейки картинка быстро меняется пока не дойдет очередь до своей по индексу. 
Что в этом случае делать? долго искал, многое пробовал(кроме библиотек, ибо по какой то причине ни одна не устанавливается корректно)

**UPD:**

В данный момент ячейки формируются так:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCellAdd

cell.imageAdd.downloaded(from: filteredData[indexPath.row].ima) }
```

Благодаря такому расширению:

```
extension UIImageView {
func downloaded(from url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
    contentMode = mode
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard
            let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
            let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
            let data = data, error == nil,
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self.image = image
        }
        }.resume()
}
func downloaded(from link: String, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
    guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
    downloaded(from: url, contentMode: mode)
}
```

}

Comment: Нужен пример, работа с ячейками неправильная.

Comment: извиняюсь, что с такой задержкой, обновил пост с тем, как формирую ячейки

 .Картинка скачивается по url, из массива с этими url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот и причина всех бед - Вы запускаете `dataTask`, но ячейки переиспользуемые. Соответственно, первая картинка для ячейки может скачаться позже чем следующие, которые скачиваются при переиспользовании. Нужно отменять задачу.

Также советую использовать [отличную библиотеку Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher).

Comment: Пытаюсь обходиться без библиотек, ибо проблемы с их установкой) Обнуляю картинку в методе - func prepareForReuse
{ 
    cell.imageAdd.image = nil;
} но видимо этого мало

Comment: @VladislavBublik а в чем именно сложности с библиотеками?

Comment: Да ошибки выдавало, даже тему создал отдельную, сейчас вроде все работает, установил Kingfisher

Answer (score 0):

Используйте в ячейке URLSessionDownloadTask

```
var downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask?

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    downloadTask?.cancel()
    downloadTask = nil
}
downloadTask = download image
```